# How can I add two variable and assign to result variable in Python?

Tags: python

I am very new to python world,Please help me how to concatenate str and int objects.

```
a = 100
b= 200
c = 'Result ='
print (c + a + b)
```

Throwing error

```
>>> print (c + a + b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

I looking output as, Result = 300

Thank in advance...!!!

Comment: To add 2 variables, use `c = a + b`.

Comment: it's clearly mentioned, you have to convert `int` to `str` or use like this `print("{0} {1} {2}".format(c,a,b))`

Comment: If you are very new, the proper course of action is to keep reading whatever instructional material you're using, rather than immediately ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = 100
b = 200
c = 'Result = '
print (c + str(int(a + b)))
```

Comment: this will not give the OP expected result

Comment: this will give something like this "Result = 300". Isn't that the Ashraf asked?

Comment: Great ..!!! thanks a lot, 

could you please explain the difference between.


print (c + str(a) + str(b)) and print (c + str(a+b))

Comment: for completeness: `str(int(a + b))`

Comment: @Rizzit Thats right

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 100
b = 200
c = 'Result = '
print("{}{}".format(c,a+b))
```

This format of coding is safe as you can change the string variable any time and you don't need to worry about output.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 100
b = 200
c = 'Result = '
print (c, (a + b))
```

Even simpler!!!

Actually, you might not need `c`.

```
a = 100
b = 200
print ('Result = ', (a + b))
```